# Cannot install URI::_foreign

Tags: centos, software-installation, perl

Well I'm trying to install URI::_foreign on my server (I have root access) I get the following errors:

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Wed, 07 Feb 2018 18:54:45 GMT
Warning: Cannot install URI::_foreign, don't know what it is.
Try the command

i /URI::_foreign/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

How I can resolve this? I've tried on 3 different CentOS systems, all the same.

Answer (score 2):

`URI::_foreign` is not a distribution or module by itself. It is one of the included modules of the Perl `URI` distribution, so just use your favorite CPAN tool to install the `URI` Perl distribution.

But you can also succeed by just installing the CentOS `perl-URI` package, no need to go to CPAN (except if you need a specific version different from the Linux distribution package).